# Converting HTMLString to attributed string not working on IOS 11

Tags: ios, swift, ios11, nsattributedstring

```
**I am trying to convert HTMLString :**
```

HTMLString not converting to attributedstring on ios 11 but works great on ios10. Here is HTMLString:
    `"<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd\">\n<html>\n<head>\n<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=UTF-8\">\n<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Style-Type\" content=\"text/css\">\n<title></title>\n<meta name=\"Generator\" content=\"Cocoa HTML Writer\">\n<style type=\"text/css\">\np.p1 {margin: 0.0px 0.0px 0.0px 0.0px; line-height: 26.0px; font: 16.0px \'.SF UI Text\'; color: #000000; -webkit-text-stroke: #000000}\nspan.s1 {font-family: \'.SFUIText-Semibold\'; font-weight: bold; font-style: normal; font-size: 16.00pt; font-kerning: none}\n</style>\n</head>\n<body>\n<p class=\"p1\"><span class=\"s1\">Hello</span></p>\n</body>\n</html>"`

```
**the above HtmlString is not formatted with below code:**

func htmlToAttr(success: (_ status: NSAttributedString?) -> Void) -> Void {
    let html = self //"<p>Hello <i>world</i>, hello</p>"
    let data = html.data(using: .utf8)!

    let att = try! NSAttributedString.init(
      data: data, options: [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType],
      documentAttributes: nil)

    let matt = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString:att)
    matt.enumerateAttribute(NSFontAttributeName,in:NSMakeRange(0,matt.length),
                            options:.longestEffectiveRangeNotRequired) { value, range, stop in

    let f1 = value as! UIFont

    let f2 = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16) //  UIFont(name:"SanFranciscoText", size: 16)
        if let f3 = applyTraitsFromFont(f1, to:f2) {
        matt.addAttribute(NSFontAttributeName, value:f3, range:range)
            success(matt)
        }
    }
//    return matt
  }
  func applyTraitsFromFont(_ f1: UIFont, to f2: UIFont) -> UIFont? {
    let t = f1.fontDescriptor.symbolicTraits
    if let fd = f2.fontDescriptor.withSymbolicTraits(t) {
      return UIFont.init(descriptor: fd, size: 0)
    }
    return nil
  }
```

The above code convert Htmlstring tio string and work on ios10

```
Everything works great on iOS 10. Don't know what's wrong.
```

Comment: I read "`try!`, what about doing a do/catch to check if an error is thrown? Also, could you clarify that when it's not working, is `att` nil? Or simply just plain text or... ?

Comment: Simply plain text shows instead of BOLD, no error/exception or null.

Comment: Could you print matt?

Comment: Finally i got a patch, i have used https://github.com/cjwirth/RichEditorView and it work fine for me.